# using TTL with bulk_index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to user bulk insert with a ttl value but I could not do it. here is the curl request I am doing.

All I am trying to do is insert some values that has certain ttl.
Does anybody tell me what I am doing wrong. I could not find any example usage about this.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://10.9.8.7:9200/_bulk?_ttl=1&op_type=create' -d '{"index": {"_type": "numbers", "_index": "index"}}
{"name": 1, "number": 1}
{"index": {"_type": "numbers", "_index": "index"}}
{"name": 2, "number": 2}
{"index": {"_type": "numbers", "_index": "index"}}
{"name": 3, "number": 3}
{"index": {"_type": "numbers", "_index": "index"}}
{"name": 4, "number": 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the error/response? Did you enable ttl in your mapping?

Default is off according to this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/ttl-field/ Also, you can set a default ttl in your mapping.

And according to this http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/bulk/, ttl should go in the body and not the url.